# Why is a rails POST/PUT format different to GET by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger

Say I have a ruby model which has a name and age attribute. A GET request for one of these objects returns something like this when using `rails generate scaffold`:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 21,
    "parent_id": 1
}
```

By default a POST/PUT to this resource expects:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "foo",
        "age": 21,
        "parent_id": 1
     }
}
```

When using nested resources configured in routes the default behaviour is to add the parent id outside of this nested hash too, e.g.: `PUT /parents/1/users`:

```
{
    "parent_id": 1,
    "user": {
        "name": "foo",
        "age": 21
     }
}
```

I can go to the controller simply enough and alter what parameters are expected, but I'd like to know why that is the case and if I risk breaking anything if changing it.

More specifically this is a Rails API and I'd like to add swagger doc generation to the API, so having this asymmetrical request body is annoying.

So in summary my questions are:

- What are the advantages of this, why is it the Rails default and what do I risk breaking by changing it?
- How best to add swagger support to the API in a way which doesn't have different GET responses vs PUT/POST (which seems like bad design to me, but maybe I'm wrong)?
- How best/should I make the API automatically add the parent id when making a call like `POST /parents/1/users`, because again the default generation doesn't support it and I'm wondering if there's a reason

Comment: The Rails API is designed for use with Rails views and forms. If you are accessing your database via something other than Rails views and forms, consider using a more generic API such as [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org).

Comment: Rails is extremely mature and makes it easy to get up and running with minimal effort. Do you have a recommendation for a ruby gem which implements jsonapi and is easy to work with (it must be ruby). There seems to be a Rails gem for jsonapi too, any experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

Tom Lord’s answer and note is probably better than mine.

---

My guess is that this mimics the behaviour of HTTP. If you GET data, you can add parameters (`?name=foo`). However, if you POST data, you tend to put the payload in the body of the request. And not have any parameters in the URL.

It’s likely that Rails thinks that you’re going put that JSON object into the body of the request. Whereas the GET request it’s going to split the key/values apart and send as parameters.

- The advantages of keeping it the way they are is that it’ll avoid a gotcha later. I’d argue this is always the best thing to do in programming, but also especially something like Rails. But, if you’re making an API I can see why you’d want to let people send data as parameters rather than a body that needs validating.
- As for Swagger, let the user know they need to send the data as a JSON string, and then use the parameters feature as expected.
- Last one is a bit tricky. I guess it’s up to the design of your API. You could pass it as part of the request. Maybe take a look through sometihng like [RESTful API Design](https://www.slideshare.net/apigee/restful-api-design-second-edition) to clarify your goal.

Comment: The core of my question is around that potential 'gotcha'. I don't want to make changes for my design which step on something I don't understand about Rails. If you know of any that would happen because of this particular change, then please, enlighten me!

Comment: I think there’s two potentials. The first is just around scaffolding, which if you keep as close as possible, it means adding new features in the future will be easy. This isn’t a big gotcha, as it is just scaffolding, and not a big deal if you go off piste. The bigger gotcha I think is around what the rest of Rails is doing. I don't know, but I think it could have implications for routing, especially if you intend to use resources. Might be worth checking http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to see if you might use this in the near-future and if it causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the advantages of this?

This is perhaps an opinion-based answer, which is generally frowned upon by StackOverflow, but here's my 2 cents.

In the GET request, you are simply being returned a resource. So the attributes are all you need to know:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo",
  "age": 21,
  "parent_id": 1
}
```

On the other hand, for this `PUT` request:

```
{
  "parent_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 21
  }
}
```

You can think of the parameters as being split into two "sections": The `parent_id` (which would normally get sent as a `path` param, not part of the request body!) is something to "search/filter" by, whereas the `user` params are the attributes of the `user` resource to update.

This logical separation of concerns is particularly useful in the context of web forms (which is what Rails was originally/primarily designed for), especially when dealing with complex queries or "nested" attributes.

> what do I risk breaking by changing it?

Nothing really.

That format, however, was "optimised" for the context of RESTful APIs and web forms.

If you'd rather use some other format then go ahead; Rails isn't forcing you to use anything here. Just beware that a naive "better design" may come back to bite you down the line.

> How best to add swagger support to the API in a way which doesn't have different GET responses vs PUT/POST (which seems like bad design to me, but maybe I'm wrong)?

You can design the API any way you like. If you want "flat parameters" everywhere, then just build the Rails application like that.

> How best/should I make the API automatically add the parent id when making a call like POST /parents/1/users, because again the default generation doesn't support it and I'm wondering if there's a reason

I'm not sure what you mean by "the default generation doesn't support it". The default generation of *what*? The swagger docs? The rails application?

Anyway... That should be implemented as a **path** parameter. The swagger docs should look something like this:

```
/parents/{parent_id}/users:
  get:
    description: '.....'
    parameters:
    - name: parent_id
      in: path
      description: 'ID of the parent'
      required: true
      type: integer
```

Comment: The default generation I'm referring to is `rails generate scaffold`, it uses strong parameters based on your input in a way which expects the nested hash.

Comment: `You can design the API any way you like. If you want "flat parameters" everywhere, then just build the Rails application like that.` So that's pretty much the crux of it, want to know why I shouldn't do that (i.e. if there is some built in rails magic I'll start to break). It seems like using ParamsWrapper and some manual massaging can get me the behaviour I want for an end user and end up with the same data structure for params on the back end, but it's potentially extra work so I want to know if it's worth it.

Comment: @yoshiwaan To reiterate what I said above: There is no "rails magic" that requires a certain API structure. However, that structure is designed to play nicely with websites - e.g. form submissions. If you want `rails generate` to create controllers in your desired format (although frankly, it's not a huge task to just manually change them!!), you could write your own `erb` controller template: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates